# Advanced installer Setup.exe - command line switch to uninstall package

Tags: command-line, advanced-installer

Using Advanced installer, I've created a package resulting in an EXE (there are deployment features that couldnt be contained within a plain MSI file).

Now, while Advanced Installer allows me to pass through command line parameters to the underlying MSI, I have no idea what parameters to pass to force the package to uninstall.

For example, the following parameters logs the setup events and instructs the underlying MSI to run passively and log its own actions.

```
"c:\MySetup.exe" /exelog "c:\log.txt" /passive /log "c:\msilog.txt"
```

The resulting commands that AdvancedInstaller executes is ultimately

```
msiexec.exe /i [path to extracted msi] /passive /log "c:\msilog.txt"
```

But try as I might, I cannot figure out how to have AdvancedInstaller launch msiexec with the /uninstall or the /x switch. For example:

```
"c:\MySetup.exe" /exelog "c:\log.txt" /x /log "c:\msilog.txt"
```

results in

```
msiexec.exe /i [path to extracted msi] /x /passive /log "c:\msilog.txt"
```

which of course fails because the /x is in the wrong place (should be in place of the /i).
What switches/parameters is the Advanced Installer exe needing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, it was buried a little obscurely in the documentation:
All 'pre-path-to-msi' parameters follow a "[option] // [optional parameters]" pattern

The following will instruct the Advanced Installer EXE bootstrap to fire off the MSI as uninstall.

**UPDATED:**

```
"c:\MySetup.exe" /exelog "c:\log.txt" /x // /log "c:\msilog.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks, I seemed to have missed that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `//` marker, for example:

```
"c:\MySetup.exe" /exelog "c:\log.txt" /x // /log "c:\msilog.txt"
```

This marker is used to replace the msiexec command line. You can read about it in the user guide: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/exe-setup-file.html

Comment: Admittedly, I've spent a good few hours in their user guide and found it frustrating. AdvancedInstaller is a pretty versatile tool, but I struggle to learn the smaller details from their user guide.